# Обработка события внутри функции

Tags: javascript

Имеется функция JS, код ниже. Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы JS брал значение поля doctypeid во время загрузки формы. То есть необходимо, если type > 9, то поля с атрибутом disabled были уже недоступны сразу после загрузки формы. Сейчас по коду нужно снова выбрать необходимый вариант doctypeid, чтобы поля стали неактивны

```
function check_disabled ()
{   
    var doctypeid=document.querySelector("[name='prevdocid']");
    var  doc_series=document.querySelector("[name='doc_series']");
    var  doc_number=document.querySelector("[name='doc_number']");
    var  doc_date=document.querySelector("[name='doc_date']");
    var  doc_series_star=document.getElementById("doc_series_star");
    var  doc_number_star=document.getElementById("doc_number_star");
    var  doc_date_star=document.getElementById("doc_date_star");
    
    var type=parseInt(doctypeid.value,10);
    if(type<9)
    {
        doc_series.required = true; 
        doc_number.required=true;
        doc_date.required=true;
        doc_series.disabled = false;    
        doc_number.disabled=false;
        doc_date.disabled=false;
        doc_series_star.innerHTML="<font color=#FF0000>*</font>";   
        doc_number_star.innerHTML="<font color=#FF0000>*</font>";
        doc_date_star.innerHTML="<font color=#FF0000>*</font>";
        
    }
    else
    {
        doc_series.required = false;    
        doc_number.required=false;
        doc_date.required=false;
        doc_series.disabled = true; 
        doc_number.disabled=true;
        doc_date.disabled=true;
        doc_series_star.innerHTML="";   
        doc_number_star.innerHTML="";
        doc_date_star.innerHTML="";
        doc_number.removeEventListener("input",input_dn) ;
        doc_series.removeEventListener("input",input_ds) ;
        doc_number.removeEventListener("invalid",invalid_dn) ;
        doc_series.removeEventListener("invalid",invalid_ds) ;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{ check_disabled(); } )`

Comment: если что, можно написать `input.required = (x > 9)` а не плодить условные операторы.

Comment: Лисенер добавить не получается, не работает.